# Jquery time picker & Date picker in table with add row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery time picker & Date picker in the table with add row.
 jQuery Clone with date picker and time picker & unique id.
In this demo, I can't be showing date picker after editing any row from 
 cloned textbox please help where I had put the wrong code.

```
<div class="container">//div start
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <div class="table-title">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Add Place Details</h2></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <button type="button" id = "btn" class="btn btn-info add-field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Time</th>
                  <th>Vehicle</th>
                  <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class = "multi-fields"  id="elements">
                <tr class = "multi-field"  id="Meal_00">
                  <td>
                      <div class="content datepicker"><input type="text" id="Field_00" class = "datepicker_recurring_start"></div>
                  </td>
                  <td><div class="bootstrap-timepicker"><input type="text"  id="Field_00" class="form-control timepicker"></div></td>
                  <td><select class="vehicle form-control"><option value = "vehicle1">vehicle1</option><option value = "vehicle2">vehicle2</option><option value = "vehicle3">vehicle3</option></select></td>
                  <td><a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>//div end
```

Comment: could  you please add the script if any and elaborate  what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: The script is too long to upload. I want cloned date picker and time picker with an add-row table.

Comment: so you just want to add one more row of same as above on button click ?